# MobileFirst 8 JMS Adapter

Tags: jms, ibm-mobilefirst, adapter

I want to upgrade the version of MobileFirst from WL v6.2 to MFP v8. The actual implementation uses a JMS Adapter for reading messages from a IBM MQ Queue to send push notification. MFP v8 no longer offers this kind of adapter and I would like to know what is the best way to read message from a Queue with the newest version.

Thanks,
Stefano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because JMS support is currently not supported, your best bet IMO would be to create your own JMS client in a Java adapter and handle it on your own there...

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncfa.html