# IBM Mobilefirst Java Adapter Session Timeout

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We are upgrading from Mobilefirst 7.1 to 8.0. Javascript JMS adapter had been taken off.
[MobileFirst 8 JMS Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38436125/mobilefirst-8-jms-adapter)
So we have to write our own JMS Java adapter.

The backend server require quite sometime to reply to MFP server. Hence our Java JMS adapter keep timeout when talk to the MQ. We know about able to increase Javascript adapter timeout time, but unable to find for JAVA. (We managed to get the data in debug mode although the adapter had been timeout.)
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2014/12/22/adapter-thread-pools-removed/

Is there any ways for us to increase the timeout time between Java Adapter to Back End System?.

Thank You.

Comment: Hi.
What is the problem - does the adapter fails? does the client stop waiting for the adapter?

Comment: @IssaharWeiss It will just fail invocation timeout at the eclipse console.

Comment: It is very strange, as there isn't any timeout on the JavaAdapter call to the backend, it is totally controllable by the developer.
Can you try it with Swagger UI or Postman?

Comment: Have you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since Java adapters are basically JAX-RS applications, and for HTTP requests [you're creating an HTTP client to perform the request](https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/AdaptersMashup/blob/release80/Adapters/HTTPAdapterJava/src/main/java/com/sample/HTTPAdapterJavaResource.java), you need to look at Java/JAX-RS APIs to increase the timeout.

See for example here: [Setting request timeout for JAX-RS 2.0 Client API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672664/setting-request-timeout-for-jax-rs-2-0-client-api)

Comment: Is there any ways to disable all IBM adapters Java Timeout? I already have my own timeout handling in Java JMS. I am using IBM message client library which is use to form IBM MQ connection and session timeout is configure there. It works fine in Java application but fail in IBM Java adapter which it session timeout by itself.